# Add a new list item with certain markup

Tags: jquery

I want to add dynamically `<li>` to my existing `<ul>` before the last-child element. But this new `<li>` must be of the following markup:

```
 <li>
    <span id="/*Previous tab's number + 1*/"> Previous tab's number +1 </span>
    <span class="x"></span>
</li>
```

How do I do that, because `.insertBefore("ul li:last-child")` can insert only bare `<li></li>` as far as I understand.

---

Here is my current example:

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
    
 $("<li></li>").insertBefore($("ul li:last-child"));
    
})
```

```css
button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.x:after {
    content: "+";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <span id="tab_1">Tab 1</span>
        <span class="x"></span>
    </li>
    
    <li>
        <span id="last">Last item</span>
        <span class="x"></span>
    </li>
    
</ul>

<button type="Button" id="btn">Create one more item</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only inserting a "bare" `<li>` elements because that is what you specified in this line:

```
$("<li></li>").insertBefore($("ul li:last-child"));
```

The `$("<li></li>")` simply represents an empty element.

You can use any element to be "inserted before". Take this as an example:

```
var newLi = $("<li>");
newLi.text("This is some new content");
newLi.addClass("some_new_class");
newLi.insertBefore("ul li:last-child");
```

In this example, the `newLi` variable can hold any element you wish. Note also that the argument passed to the `insertBefore` function can be a selector, you don't need the actual object. See my example, I used the same selector but didn't use the actual object:

```
.insertBefore("ul li:last-child")
```

---

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
     var newLi = $("<li>");
     newLi.text("This is some new content");
     newLi.addClass("some_new_class");
     newLi.insertBefore("ul li:last-child");   
})
```

```css
button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.x:after {
    content: "+";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <span id="tab_1">Tab 1</span>
        <span class="x"></span>
    </li>
    
    <li>
        <span id="last">Last item</span>
        <span class="x"></span>
    </li>
    
</ul>

<button type="Button" id="btn">Create one more item</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use a combination of the `:last` selector and prepend/append function to accomplish what you need.

```
$("li:last").prepend("<li>*****</li>")
```

Hope it works.